# Struggling to find element in Chrome Inspect - how to customise?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to find the properties of an element using Chrome Inspect. I am trying to make a custom CSS change to a wordpress site.

Looking on https://thehayexchange.co.uk/ - I want to use the same grey border around the "Latest Ads" thumbnails. I want to use that border around my long advertisements (at the bottom of the page, currently a large picture saying "My Fancy Feathers").

I can see the DIV class is: awpcp-listings-widget-item awpcp-listings-widget-item-with-left-thumbnail-in-desktop awpcp-listings-widget-item-with-thumbnail-above-in-mobile  awpcp-listings-widget-item-without-thumbnail

However, when I go into the WordPress CSS item editor and apply the border, I can't find the style.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this style to your long ad to achieve a similar effect:

```
border: 5px solid #f2f2f2;
border-radius: 5px;
```

I used the inspector tool to get the color and the border radius.

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you. And how would I align to the center? 

I have gone with     align-content: center;     but it does not work.

Comment: `align-content` is for flexible content only (e.g. `display: flex`), you should use `margin: auto` [check here for css basics](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)